# how to pass more than two parameters to modal ng2 bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, ng2-bootstrap

I have to pass a flag in my Dialog Component. It must be like this

```
 this.dialogService.addDialog(ModalDialogComponent, { title: 'History', message: this.comments, isHistoryModel:true});
```

My ModalDialogComponent:

```
export class ModalDialogComponent extends DialogComponent < ModalDialogModel, null > implements ModalDialogModel {
    title: string;
    message: any;
    isHistoryModel: boolean;
    constructor(dialogService: DialogService) {
        super(dialogService);
    }
}
```

Error snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add

```
isHistoryModel:boolean
```

into your

```
ModalDialogModel
```

Comment: Got it, I have to add the new property to ModalDialogModel interface. Thanks